# How to get IntPtr of the array within List<T>?

Tags: c#, marshalling, intptr

I'm using a library which has a function `SendBuffer(int size, IntPtr pointer)` with `IntPtr` as a parameter.

```
 var list = new List<float>{3, 2, 1};
 IntPtr ptr = list.getPointerToInternalArray();
 SendBuffer(ptr, list.Count);
```

How to get `IntPtr` from the array stored in `List<T>` (and/or `T[]`)?

Comment: Call ToArray, or is that too slow for you?

Comment: @HansPassant: If he creates the array on the managed side, this has the risk that the GC relocates the array making the address invalid.

Comment: ToArray() allocates memory and makes a copy, this is performance critical section. The array is sent every *frame* and it's big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The array is sent every frame and it's big

In that case it might be warranted to access the internal backing array that `List` uses. This is a hack and brittle in the face of future .NET versions. That said .NET uses a very high compatibility bar and they probably would not change a field name in such a core type. Also, for performance reasons it is pretty much guaranteed that `List` will always use a single backing array for its items. So although this is a high risk technique it might be warranted here.

Or, better yet, write your own List that you control and that you can get the array from. (Since you seem to be concerned with perf I wonder why you are using `List<float>` anyway because accessing items is slower compared to a normal array.)

Get the array, then use `fixed(float* ptr = array) SendBuffer(ptr, length)` to pin it and pass it without copying memory.

There is not need to use the awkward and slow `GCHandle` type here. Pinning using `fixed` uses an IL feature to make this super fast. Should be near zero cost.

Answer (score 4):

If this is a P/Invoke call to an unmanaged code you should retrieve the pinned address of the buffer (to prevent that GC relocate the buffer) and pass this to the method:

```
// use an array as a buffer
float[] buffer = new float[]{3, 2, 1};

// pin it to a fixed address:
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    // retrieve the address as a pointer and use it to call the native method
    SendBuffer(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), buffer.Length);
}
finally
{
    // free the handle so GC can collect the buffer again
    handle.Free();
}
```

Comment: using `fixed` would be more elegant: `fixed(float* p = array) Send(p, array.length)`

Comment: @firda: Of course, but only if you are allowed to use unsafe code in your project

Comment: @taffer why wouldn't he be allowed to use unsafe code? It has the same security implications as pinned handles and PInvoke.

Comment: This looks awesome, is there any chance for a similar mechanism to work for List<T>? From what I heard List<T> uses an array internally.

Comment: `List<T>.ToArray()`? ;)

Answer (score 2):

No guarantee that the internal representation of a `List<T>` is going to be a single array... in fact it's pretty likely that it's not.  So you need to create a local array copy using `ToArray` in order for this to work.

Once you have, there are a couple of options.

First you can use the `fixed` keyword to pin the array and get a pointer to it:

```
T[] buffer = theList.ToArray();
unsafe 
{
    fixed (T* p = buffer)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
        SomeFunction(ptr);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can tell the garbage collector to fix the data in memory until you're done with the operation, like this:

```
GCHandle pinned = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = pinned.AddrOfPinnedObject();

SomeFunction(ptr);

pinnedArray.Free();
```

(Or see taffer's answer with more error handling).

In both cases you need to finish with the value before returning, so you can't use either method to get an `IntPtr` to the array as a return value.  Doing it this way minimizes the opportunity for that pointer to be used for evil.

Comment: `GCHandle.Alloc` actually doesn't create a copy. If `SomeFunction` manipulates the buffer it will be reflected in your array.